# Define an overloaded + operator C++

Tags: c++

Eu não consegui resolver a seguinte questão:

Fill in the blanks to define an overloaded +operator for the class "Test".

```
Test Test::______(Test obj){
___newObj;
newObj.mem=
mem__obj.mem;
return newObj;
}
```

Eu não sei como preencher os espaços com as seguintes altenativas:
 operator const Test class

Perdão, errei na digitação. o correto das alternativas é assim: class operator+ const+ Test

Comment: Tem certeza que isto?, não está amontoado demais? Tá difícil de entender escrito dessa forma. Tem 4 opções e 3 lacunas mesmo?

Comment: @bigown, eu não digitei desse jeito, eu apertei enter onde deveria ter apertado, mas tudo aparece na mesma linha. Eu encontrei a resposta, no primeiro espaço se digita operator+, no segundo espaço se digita Test e se coloca o sinal + no terceiro espaço. Muito obrigado pela atenção e paciência.

Comment: vou ver se consigo editar o código para que ele apareça como deve aparecer

Comment: É, eu sei, mesmo assim está amontoado demais, não tem espaços, tem coisa que pulou linha sem fazer sentido, eu acho que tem erros de digitação aí, se não tiver ainda está difícil de entender. Use o `{}` ou CTRL-K no código todo

Comment: Eu digitei direito, mas aparece tudo na mesma linha não sei porque.

Comment: Eu mesmo respondi esta questão, como falei, no primeiro espaço se digita operator+, no segundo espaço se digita Test e se coloca o sinal + no terceiro espaço.

Comment: @bigown, quando se aperta no botão editar, o código aparece na maneira que digitei, aparece os espaços, as linhas, aparece digitado corretamente, não é possível você ver isso em algum lugar?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo código escrito é difícil entender mas, será que 
é isto que você está tentando fazer?

```
Test Test::operator+ (Test obj) const
{
 Test newObj;
 newObj.mem = obj.mem;
 return newObj;
}
```

Comment: eu tentei apenas preencher os espaços em branco, esta é uma questão do curso C++ Tutorial Course do Sololearn, eu terminei esse curso e o curso Ruby Tutorial Course, agora estou fazendo o curso Swift Fundamental, eu vou tentar encontrar a resposta do que tentei fazer quando postei esta dúvida sobre o curso de C++.

Comment: tesseractBird, essa é a resposta: no primeiro espaço se digita operator+, no segundo espaço se digita Test e no último espaço se digita apenas +.

Comment: @bigown, por favor, fale sua opinião sobre os meus últimos comentários.